# Confusion with modules and refactoring JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, module, refactoring

I am attempting to adopt 'best practices' for writing Javascript, specifically writing modules. I am refactoring a piece of code at the moment but am having some problems with the jquery selectors.

The first (ugly) code is functioning as I'd expect. However, the click event on the module isn't firing and it seems like the selectors aren't being properly assigned.

Any advice on syntax, organization or general abstraction philosophy would be greatly appreciated. And more importantly, what am I doing wrong in the module?

```js
// Messy jQuery

$(function() {
  $div1 = $('#div1');
  $div2 = $('#div2');
  $button = $('#button');

  $('#button').click(function() {
    $div1.fadeOut();
    $div2.fadeIn();
  })  
});

// Attempted Module

(function (){

  var interface = {
    init: function() {
      this.cacheDom();
      this.bindEvents();
    },
    cacheDom: function() {
      this.$div1 = $('#div1');
      this.$button = this.$div1.find('button');
      this.$div2 = $('#div2');
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
      this.$button.on('click', this.swapDiv.bind(this));
    },
    swapDiv: function() {
      this.$div1.fadeOut();
      this.$div2.fadeIn();
    }
   }
   interface.init();
})()
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <button id="button">Swap Div</button>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code and it works. I think your are calling self-executing anonymous function in `<head>` tag before html render . So, jQuery can't find and bind the event listener to your button. Wrap your self-executing function in `$()` or move to before the end of`body` tag.

```js
(function (){

    var interface = {
        init: function() {
            this.cacheDom();
            this.bindEvents();
        },
        cacheDom: function() {
            this.$div1 = $('#div1');
            this.$button = this.$div1.find('button');
            this.$div2 = $('#div2');
        },
        bindEvents: function() {
            this.$button.on('click', this.swapDiv.bind(this));
        },
        swapDiv: function() {
            this.$div1.fadeOut();
            this.$div2.fadeIn();
        }
    };
    interface.init();
})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
    <button id="button">Swap Div</button>
</div>

<div id="div2">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Huh, that is interesting because it's not working inside my rails student project. Good to know the code is working though and seems to just be an asset loading issue.

Comment: Just woke up and finally absorbed what you were talking about. You were right, thanks for your help.

Comment: @JoelB Glad to hear that